# Issues using SCAP Workbench on Fedora 35

Tags: fedora, openscap

I have an issue with installing and running Flatpacks because I installed SCAP Workbench which changed my default system settings (Fedora 35).

Answer (score 0):

could you share more details? Did you only install SCAP Workbench or did you also execute any scan or remediation using SCAP Workbench? Does Flatpak print any error message?

Comment: I installed SCAP Workbench and then I scanned and used all thee available remediation using SCAP Workbench. I did have to re-install the OS becasue nothing worked. This message appears when I try to install something : Unable to install software_name Error _1 running transaction.